# implementation DAO with Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, dao

when I implemented DAO with Hibernate I found some code as below,

```
public List<T> findAll(Class<T> entityClazz)
{
    return find("select en from "
        + entityClazz.getSimpleName() + " en");
}
```

my question is, what is the 'en', is it a parameter or what?

Comment: It's the entity alias. To understand it better take a look over the JPQL specification.

Comment: but one more question, I know it's alias, but do I need to define it myself before I can use it? where should I define it? or it's predefined by the specification?

Answer (score 0):

You can give alias names for your entities while writing HQL or Native SQL queries:

Refer to the [hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html):

> In order to refer to the Cat in other parts of the query, you will
>   need to assign an alias. For example:
>
> **from Cat as cat**